# Duvida iniciante ! Manipulando series

Tags: python, data

Estou fazendo minhas primeiras análises com Pandas em Python 3. Estou praticando com um dataset de game of thrones que contém as mortes nos livros.

Uma das colunas do dataframe se refere a casa e nessa coluna existem valores repetidos do tipo: Stark / Casa Stark.

Gostaria de saber como faço para remover a palavra "casa" da referida coluna.

Alguém consegue por favor me ajudar ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar a função `replace`:

```
str = "Casa Stark"
str = str.replace("Casa ", "")
print(str) #Retorna Stark
```

Terá que usar dentro de um loop, pode fazer algo assim:

```
array = [
  ["coluna 1", "coluna 2", "X"],
  ["coluna 1", "coluna 2", "Stark"],
  ["coluna 1", "coluna 2", "Casa Stark"],
  ["coluna 1", "coluna 2", "Casa Z"],
  ["coluna 1", "coluna 2", "Casa Stark"],
]

for elemento in array:
  elemento[2] = elemento[2].replace("Casa ", "")
  print(elemento[2])
```

Comment: Para fazer isso também pode ser usado list comprehensions, algo como arrayCorrigido = [[elemento[0],elemento[1],elemento[2].replace("Casa ","")] for elemento in array]